# System.StackOverflowException intersection error

Tags: vb.net

I want my program to take a variable, and find letters A-Z. I have made this section of my program in a module to be shared between 2 different forms.

variables are passed from `form1` and are processed by the module and then sent back again to `form1`. the problem is I think some sort of bug in the code but I cant identify it.

---

```
Public Function UPCASES(ByRef password1, points) As Boolean
  Dim intersection As IEnumerable(Of Char)
  intersection = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Intersect(password1)  
  'System.StackOverflowException error ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  If intersection.Count() = 1 Then
     points = 5
  Else
     points = 0
  End If

  Return UPCASES(password1, points)
End Function
```

Comment: What is this method supposed to do? You are always calling it again at the method which is causing the `StackOverflowException`, but i don't know what the method should do, so i can't help to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to programming, it is simply meant to compare variables and look for capitals in password1. you said I am calling it again, how?

Comment: `Return UPCASES(password1, points)`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the method itself at the method end, that causes the `StackOverflowException`:

```
Return UPCASES(password1, points)
```

I guess this method should check if the password contains uppercase letters, then use:

```
Dim containsUpperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Intersect(password1).Any()
```

So no need to create a method just for this one-liner, if you need a method:

```
Public Function ContainsUpperCaseLetter(password1 As String) As Boolean
    Return "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Intersect(password1).Any()
End Function
```

---

Side-note: you should  change your default project settings to use `Option Strict ON`(`Off` is default unfortunately). Then you will be able to write much more safe, robust and performant code after you have learned a lot about .NET types because you have to fix the compiler errors.

Comment: I couldn't agree more! I learned about Option Strict when I first arrived at SO and have been using it ever since.  How about Dim containsUpperCase  As Boolean =